# how to define relationship between InfluxDB measurements (tables)

Tags: database-design, orm, time-series, data-science, influxdb

**Need some explaination**,

- How to define relation b/w (InfluxDB) time series database?
- Like N-hibernate support multiple databases, we can shift from mySQL to SQL 
  easy. Does Time series database have any similar ORM solution?
- I have worked on relational database in which we use primary key and foreign keys to define relation between tables, and there different type relation (One-one, one-to-many, many-to-many).
- Can we define similar relationship into InfluxDB? if, not how can we acheive relationship between tables (measurements)?

Meanwhile, InfluxDB provide us Tag keys (indexed), should we use these to define relationship between tables or measurements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InfluxDB is not relational DB = no primary/foreign keys, no joins of measurements, etc.
In theory you can use tags as a work around, but they are designated for data with low cardinality = if you have many records with unique ID tag, then you will need a lot of memory.

I recommend to read about [InfluxDB schema/data layout](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/) and review if InfluxDB is really good DB for your relational DB replacement. Generally, it is not a good idea.